# how java handles long and double in 32 bit architecture

Tags: java, double, 32bit-64bit, long-integer

how java handles the double and long in the 32 bit platform, I knew that java is platform independent, So how exactly it do that.
My query is like for long does java stores the values as first 32 bit and another 32 bit in one and another memory location, how do we identify them ?

Comment: Obvious question: why do you care? At the JVM level all of these have a well defined behavior, the rest is implementation details

Comment: just I am interested in it ..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Java (JVM) stores / writes the first 32 bits and then the next 32 bits one after another. That's why writing to long (or say double) fields are not thread-safe (unless they are marked as volatile)

Comment: @Codebender - Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) :). `volatile` ensures atomicity of writes in case of long / double fields

Comment: seems is it possible that a thread reading first half in the long value, then can I get the demo code .. with results **#codebender**..

Comment: @Deepaksai - create 2 threads. One will read from a long field and another will write to the same long field. Put this reading / writing in a loop and see what happens

Comment: @Deepaksai - This is not *twitter* use `@` to address people

Comment: why would `volatile` ensure atomicity? `volatile` establishes happens-before relationship. if one thread writes first 32 bits, and then jvm preemptively stops this thread then the other thread sees these udpated 32 bits, but the second 32 bits would make no sense for second thread.